# How to find duplicate properties in object

Tags: ruby

all objects

```
[#<User:0x0000000002afbae8
  @uid="john">,
  @name="john doe">,
#<User:0x0000000002b026e0
  @uid="mike">,
  @name="mike spencer">,
#<User:0x0000000002b012e0
  @uid="mike">,
  @name="mike ferrell">,
]
```

currently i only get the last saved object,

```
[<User:0x0000000002b012e0
      @uid="mike">,
      @name="mike ferrell">,
]
```

What would be an easiest way to check if object has duplicate properties, and if so, return all of them?
Thank you!

```
  class User
         attr_accessor :uid,:name
         @@all = []

     def initialize(uid, name)
       @uid = uid
       @name = name
       @@all << self
     end

     def self.select_duplicate
       seen = []
       duplicates = []

       @@all.each do |user|
         if seen.include?(user.uid)
           duplicates << user
         else
           seen << user.uid
         end
       end
     end
   end
```

Comment: Do you want to check all properties? Or just the uid?

Comment: i want to check the uid

Comment: Why would you have two different objects with the same uid in the first place?

Comment: the uid is the sync response from google directory, will try to check the duplicate then update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Hash whose key is the uid and the value is an Array of users with that uid. Then only the values which are larger than one are duplicates.

```
users_by_uid = @@all.each_with_object({}) { |user,m|
  m[user.uid] << user
}

dup_uids = users_by_uid.filter { |uid,users|
  users.size > 1
}

dup_uids.each { |uid,users|
  puts "Users #{users.map(&name).join(", ")} have the same uid #{uid}"
}
```

---

And, [as @AlexGolubenko pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055273/how-to-find-duplicate-properties-in-object/61055504?noredirect=1#comment108018382_61055504), you can replace the `each_with_object` with [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). It does the same thing, but more compact, and perhaps a touch faster.

```
users_by_uid = @@all.group_by(&:uid)
```

Comment: I think, instead of `#each_with_object` it might be solved with`#group_by(&:uid)`